# Sort None last in Scala List

Tags: scala

I have data coming from Avro that can be null and I need to sort it. What I want to do is pick the first record for a list but make sure that nulls are last.

```
case class Data(k: Int, v: String)
val list = List(Data(42, "xyz"), Data(1, null), Data(1, "baz"))
```

What I want is `Data(1, "baz")` because I want to sort on the `k` but then on the `v` with all nulls sorted last. Is that possible?

Comment: I dont know much about scala. Can you make 2 lists, 1 with nulls, 1 without and then concatenate them?

Answer (score 2):

Using [SortWtih](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Array.html#sortWith(lt:(A,A)=%3EBoolean):Repr) can help us

```
val res0 =  List((10,null), (1,2), (2,3), (3,null), (4,5))
res0.sortWith( (first, second) => {
  if(first._2 == null) false
  else if(second._2 == null) true
  else false
})
```

Or even shorter

```
res0.sortWith( _._2 != null && _._2 == null)
```

Results:

```
List((1,2), (2,3), (4,5), (10,null), (3,null))
```

Comment: @MaxPower "make sure that nulls are last." and "Sort None last in Scala List" indicates that the order is correct

But you'd like the list to be sorted also on their key, is that right ? Can you provide the result wanted and/or other examples?

Answer (score 1):

You can use sortWith function defined on collections.

```
case class Data(k: Int, v: String)
val list = List(Data(42, "xyz"), Data(1, null), Data(1, "baz"))

val sorted = list.sortWith((d1, d2) => 
  if (d1.k != d2.k) {
  d1.k < d2.k
} else {
  if (d1.v == null) false
  else if (d2.v == null) true
  else d1.v.compareTo(d2.v) == 1
})

println(sorted) // List(Data(1,baz), Data(1,null), Data(42,xyz))
```